# after effects greyscale bmp as mask

Tags: mask, effects, adobe-after-effects

I created a grey scale bmp image (depthmap) which corresponds with the first frame in a short video clip. my intention is to use the bmp image as a mask and then track the mask for the remainder of the clip. how would i do this? my experience with after effects is limited. Any help would be appreciated.